# Solr stats.facet with multi-valued field

Tags: solr, solrj, facet, faceted-search, solr5

I am in a process of upgrading Solr from 1.x to Solr 5.2.1.[This jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1782) says faceting on stats with multi-valued field has been taken back. So when I try to do it says

> Stats can only facet on single-valued fields, not: market

market is multi-valued field in my schema.

Does any workaround or solution exists to achieve this ? OR I have to fetch desired data from Solr and calculate statistics at my code level?

Comment: Is there any reason why the linked ["how to actually do this?"](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-CombiningStatsComponentWithPivots) on the ticket isn't applicable?